# Prevent JSF action method execution after a filter redirect

Tags: jsf, redirect, servlet-filters

I have implemented a Servlet Filter to do my system's authorization and where needed I redirect the user using this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    ...

    if(!isLoggedIn(currentUser)){
        if(isSecurePage(requestedPage)){
            redirectUser(resp,USER_LOGIN_PAGE);
        }
        else{ // Carry on
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!isSecurePage(requestedPage)){
            redirectUser(resp,USER_WELCOME_PAGE);
        }
        else if(!canAccess(currentUser,requestedPage)){
            redirectUser(resp,req.getContextPath() + USER_DENIED_PAGE);
        }
        else{ // Carry on
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
    }
}

private void redirectUser(HttpServletResponse response, String page) throws IOException {
    response.sendRedirect(page);
}
```

The redirect happens correctly. My issue is that although ACCESS_DENIED_PAGE is displayed, the JSF action method behind the original request is still executed (a FacesMessage that it creates is displayed in the ACCESS_DENIED_PAGE, for example).

How to prevent this?

Comment: where is the code for `FacesMessage`? and where is the `ACCESS_DENIED_PAGE` happening?

Comment: Thank you for posting. I will post the code tomorrow, as soon as I get to my work.

Comment: This information is irrelevant to the concrete problem.

Comment: BalusC, can you shed a light, please?

Comment: As stated in my deleted answer, the symptoms say that `chain.doFilter()` is still invoked after a `response.sendRedirect()`, but the code posted so far in your update doesn't do that. So I don't know. Perhaps the code in the question is incomplete, or you're just not running the code you think you're running. This is not answerable based on the information so far.